# How do i create postgres to oracle dblink?

Tags: postgresql, oracle11g, postgresql-9.2, dblink

How do I create dblink in postgres 9.2 ? I want to be able to use it using @ link in oracle? I am using postgres 9.2 64bit. DBlink is from postgres 9.2 to Oracle 11g.

Answer (score 20):

If you need to access postgresql FROM Oracle:

http://dbaspot.wordpress.com/2013/05/29/how-to-access-postgresql-from-oracle-database/

If you need to access Oracle FROM postgresql:

http://pgxn.org/dist/oracle_fdw/

Comment: The FDW is the way to go

Comment: @Leo @Frank Heikens : Any experience with FDW and `join` queries with Oracle? It is still in beta version and I need something reliable and maintained.

Comment: While this may answer the question, all the content is "in another castle" behind the links to third-party content. If link-rot occurs then this answer will have no useful content and it would be better if you included sufficient detail in your answer to actually answer the question.